# Lagged circle reveal animation

Tags: android, animation

I am using this animation when I press a button:

```
void circleAnimationEnter(final View view, final View view2) {


    // get the center for the clipping circle
    int cx = Math.round(view2.getX() + view2.getWidth() / 2);
    int cy = Math.round(view2.getY() - view2.getHeight() / 2);

    // get the final radius for the clipping circle
    int finalRadius = Math.max(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());

    // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
    Animator anim;
    Animation animation;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
        // make the view visible and start the animation
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        anim.setDuration(1000);
        anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        anim.start();
    } else {
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.animate()
                .translationX(0)
                .setDuration(500)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

View1 is the view to hide/show, and view2 is the button to press.

And the same animation (with some changes obviusly), to hide when I press in the same button to change the visibility again.

The problem is that the first time that I press the button, the animation is lagged (the view is appearing with circle animation), but the next times that I press the button, the view visibility changes with the animation (both, show and hide) perfectly.

I am using a CollapsingToolbarLayout, maybe this can be the problem?

Is it lag? or just the first time Android is not getting the correctly X and Y?

Thank you for your help and sorry for my english!

EDIT:

The problem is about getting the values for cx and cy.

```
Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    // get the center for the clipping circle
    cx = Math.round(width-width*10/100);
    cy = Math.round(height-height*38/100);

    initialRadius = Math.max(width*3/2, height*3/2);
    finalRadius = initialRadius;
```

My animation is not lagged anymore, but the problem is that cx and cy are changing if the the toolbar is collapsed or expanded... (I don't understand this, because I am getting the screen size, so my cx and cy should be the same always...)

Comment: So you claim, that `cx` is different depending on the state (expanded/collapsed) of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`?

Comment: @azizbekian check my answer!

Answer (score 0):

I solved, the problem was the app bar when it was collapsed or not...

```
final AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            // get the center for the clipping circle
            cx = Math.round(floatingActionButton.getX() + floatingActionButton.getWidth() / 2);

            boolean fullyExpanded = (appBarLayout.getHeight() - appBarLayout.getBottom()) == 0;

            if (!fullyExpanded) {
                cy = Math.round(floatingActionButton.getY() - floatingActionButton.getHeight());
            } else {
                cy = Math.round(floatingActionButton.getY() + floatingActionButton.getHeight()/2) - appBarLayout.getHeight();
            }

            initialRadius = Math.max(width * 3 / 2, height * 3 / 2);
            finalRadius = initialRadius;
        }
    });
```

With that code I got the fab button cx/cy perfectly and I added a 3/2 to radius to avoid height/width issues with the circle animation effect.